# Opening .tiff gives me a plot.window() error

Tags: r, plot, raster, spatial, geotiff

I created a raster and saved it as a .tif file. However, when I tried to open the .tiff, I get the following error:

```
> plot("20200105.tif")
Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'ylim' values
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : NAs introduced by coercion
2: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
3: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

The strange thing is, before I saved the file it worked fine.

How do I manage this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This make no sense

```
plot("20200105.tif")
```

You are trying to plot a character string
Instead do

```
library(raster)
r <- raster("20200105.tif")
# or
# b <- brick("20200105.tif")
plot(r)
```

Comment: Yes, I realized I had incorrectly tried to open it.